# How to change color text of Text Meshpro Inputfield

Tags: unity-game-engine

With Inputfield we easy change color of text by :

```
Text text = _inputfield.transform.FindChild("Text").GetComponent<Text>();
text.color=Color.Red;
```

How can i do it with TMP_Inputfield(Inputfield Text Meshpro)

Answer (score 5):

Wrap your text with `<color>` tag. 
For example:
`This text is <color=red>RED</color> and this is <color=#ce490e>Orange</color>` 
and assign it to `text` variable of your textmeshpro

[image: Look At Here]

Comment: thank for your reply , but it doesn't solve the problem !

Comment: show me your final Text variable please, I added some screenshots for you

Answer (score 1):

TextMesh Pro inputs render the text by using `TextMeshProUGUI` nested under the input.  Typically there are two, one for the Placeholder text and one for the typed text.  There are several ways you can get them, but here is a quick example getting the typed text (named Text in the Unity UI):

```cs
var textInput = myGameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI>()
                   .First(c => c.gameObject.name == "Text");
textInput.color = new Color();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem 5 minutes ago and I find no good answer on google but I find a solution.

```
myText.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().faceColor = Color.red;
```